What kind of weapon is Choe Gu Sung holding in episode 16 of Psycho Pass?
!!WARNING: WHOLE QUESTION IS SPOILER FOR EPISODE 16, SEASON 1 OF PSYCHO PASS. PROCEED WITH CAUTION.!!
In Season 1, episode 16 of the anime series Psycho Pass, Shogo Makishima's accomplice Choe Gu-Sung went into the underground levels of the Sibyl Nona tower to discover the truth about the system. After successfully hacking the security software, he was able to breach the last door blocking his way and managed to capture the truth of the Sibyl System (a network of criminally asymptotic brains) in his phone. However, Joshu Kasei appeared and activated a dominator (presumably Shusei Kagari's) on him. After realizing he is going to be shot, Choe Gu-Sung turned around and shot Joshu simultaneously with a gun he carried into the underground levels. After Choe had been killed Joshu is seen struggling to stand, being quite severely injured and exposes her true identity, an android. Her face and part of her body was burned. My question is what type of weapon did Choe use? Looks like a gun of some kind, but certainly not a dominator or any similar weapon. Judging by its appearance, it's also not a traditional firearm. So, what exactly is it? I'll greatly appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks in advance!



Note: I've seen another Anime & Manga question what's happening to Joshu in Sibyl's core, but I'm not so sure if the gun was an acid gun, since the damage to Joshu's body was quite severe. Still, if you're all sure that it is an acid gun, then just tell me.
